# What does "Eigentum statt Miete" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning, german-to-english, vocabulary

I'm looking for renting a house in Germany and I encountered this phrase. What does it exactly mean?
The price was a lot higher than a normal price for renting an apartment.

Does this mean a **whole year deposit** and after the period, my whole amount will be return back to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase literally means *ownership instead of rent*. It’s hard to tell without further context, but you may have seen an offer for buying a home, combined with a loan. In that case, you would pay a certain amount regularly for the next ten or fifteen or twenty years until you have paid back the loan and the home is yours.